# Changing parameters after bind in Struts 2

Tags: java, data-binding, struts2, interceptor, interceptorstack

I have an action that receives some parameters from user (e.g. date). This action produces many different reports, so it has many different methods. I need to *tune* those parameters (set a time to midnight) before every method. The `prepare` method is executed before parameters are bound. Is there any other interceptor or any other convention that allows me to do that?

Comment: Why the downvote ? It is a legit question imho... +1

Comment: What is the "tuning"?  You are tweaking the incoming request parameters after they are moved onto the action?

Comment: @chad - user input string. struts automatically converts it to date, validates it and set it to the action's fields. but (probably) struts set time to 23:59. and i need to set it to midnight, before struts starts a business method

Comment: @piotrek  I recommend that you explore why the date converter is not working for you. If it's a bug, submit it.  If you just need something different from date conversion than the normal behavior, I recommend that you write your own converter.  It's not very hard and it will provide the clean solution.

Comment: Or use a validator method on your action to "validate" the value after the conversion . . . the validators will run before your action is invoked . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `<interceptor-ref name="paramsPrepareParamsStack"/>`

> ```xml
> <!-- An example of the params-prepare-params trick. This stack
>     is exactly the same as the defaultStack, except that it
>     includes one extra interceptor before the prepare interceptor:
>     the params interceptor.
>
>     This is useful for when you wish to apply parameters directly
>      to an object that you wish to load externally (such as a DAO
>      or database or service layer), but can't load that object
>      until at least the ID parameter has been loaded. By loading
>      the parameters twice, you can retrieve the object in the
>      prepare() method, allowing the second params interceptor to
>      apply the values on the object. -->
> ```

If you are using the *Convention Plugin* apply it on action

```java
@Action(value="action1", interceptorRefs=@InterceptorRef("paramsPrepareParamsStack"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to go (cheap if you are coding right now, expensive if you've already coded everything) would be to modularize every action you have to perform in one single Struts2 Action.

Then you will have something like an `BaseReportAction`, containing all the common attributes and methods shared using `protected` instead of `private`,  doing your tuning on parameters and the common operations in the `execute()` method;

And one Action for each report extending the BaseReportAction, let's say

> ExcelReportAction, PdfReportAction, etc...

or

> MinimalReportAction, CompleteReportAction, etc...

or also

> DailyReportAction, MonthlyReportAction, etc...

And the only requirement would be using `super.execute();` as first statement of every child Action's `execute()` method.

This way you could take advantage of the inheritance, to have a lot of smaller, cleaner  (eventually packaged into several sub-packages) Actions instead of one huge Action with a lots of methods.

All the utility methods used by few reports would be available only for those reports, not for all the others (let's say PDF and XLS stuff for example)...

You could benefit of the XML Validation too for different Actions (maybe one report requires different inputs from another).

Finally, your tuning-up code would be Thread-Safe (Actions are Thread-Safe, Interceptors don't).

But as said, this is a choice of implementation that better suits the pre-code phase (even if it's not that hard to refactor, according to the size of the web application...).

Comment: i think i can do the same calling `tuneParameters()` instead of `super.xxx`. but that still violates DRY

Comment: You can do that but it's not the same. Let's say tomorrow you wanna call ten different methods in `execute()`, then you would have to add 9 rows into every `execute()` method of every Action. Let's say you change the name of the `tuneParameters()` method, you will have to change it into all the other actions, etc. With super, you write it once and you forget it. The only possible error would be you forget to write it the first time, quickly detectable and fixable... however the real point is in the other benefits listed (and this is one way to go, not the only one :)