# Struts2 prepare interceptor?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, parameters, struts2, interceptor

Struts2 documentation on `prepare` interceptor says:

> A typical use of this is to run some logic to load an object from the
>   database so that when parameters are set they can be set on this
>   object. For example, suppose you have a *User* object with two
>   properties: *id* and *name*. Provided that the *params* interceptor is
>   called twice (once before and once after this interceptor), you can
>   load the *User* object using the id property, and then when the second
>   *params* interceptor is called the parameter *user.name* will be set, as
>   desired, on the actual object loaded from the database.

I am not able to understand this what changes it making to the `User` object.
Can anyone explain with some code? Or give a link where it explains?

Comment: In first run you can fetch user by id and on second run when user instance is already fetched name will be set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical usage of the `paramsPrepareParamsStack`. You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13491559/573032) answer too. An example of usage this stack you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20130845/573032).

The way you initialize the action instance might vary, that's why this stack could apply. Typically you might just instantiate a `User` object to accept parameters instead of retrieving it from the database.