# How to pass JSP iterator list to action in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, parameters, struts2, ognl

I have a JSP with an iterator list that iterates over an object created in the action with getters/setters.

I'm able to pull the mapped value from the action to the JSP iterator, now I want to be able to pass the JSP iterator list back to the action class to map the object but, I realized that it does not call my setter method.

**Here is my JSP:**

```
<s:iterator  status="stat" value="parameterList" >
    <tr id="<s:property value="#stat.index"/>">
        <td><s:textfield id="parameterList[%{#stat.index}].queryParameter" name="parameterList[%{#stat.index}].queryParameter"  cssClass="size30" labelposition="left"  ></s:textfield> </td>
        <td><s:textfield id="parameterList[%{#stat.index}].parameterValue" name="parameterList[%{#stat.index}].parameterValue"  cssClass="size30" labelposition="left"  ></s:textfield> </td>
    </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

**and this is a snippet of the action:**

```
private List<QueryParameter> parameterList = new ArrayList<QueryParameter>();

public void setParameterList(List<QueryParameter> parameterList) {
    this.parameterList = parameterList;
}

public DQA getDqaObject() {
    return dqa;
}
```

The getter gets called fine when I navigate to the JSP, but when I submit from the JSP, I am expecting the value that I put into the text field iterator should call and update the object in the action file, but the setter is not being called.

Comment: You're missing a `getParameterList`.

Comment: There is a getParameterList, just forgot to copy and paste it in this question

Comment: As a point of terminology you're not passing an "iterator list", you're relying on value conversions to rebuild the list from the parameters you're sending back in the request.

Comment: @DaveNewton yes you're correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue, the problem was that in my getter(Which I forgot to post in the question) there were some logic that was preventing the getter to proceed to actually call the objects setter to set the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

OGNL doesn't call a setter method when new object is created. Also you don't need it if you want to update existing object. It should be initialized before the action is populated.

[`prepare` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/prepare-interceptor.html) can call your action if it implements `Preparable` to execute `prepare()` method where you can initialize the object to be updated.

If you need a parameter to retrieve your object from the database you can use `paramsPrepareParams` interceptor's stack. You can see description [Changing parameters after bind in Struts 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13491559/573032).

Also don't use `ModelDriven` interface because it doesn't work correctly by default with the above stack. It requires reconfiguring the default stack to make the model pushed before [`params` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/parameters-interceptor.html) fires or otherwise you have to handle parameters manually, i.e. from the action context or `ParametersAware` which is already deprecated.